# Constant definition and template

Tags: c++, templates, types, casting

Jim coding some template class for math usage like vector 2d for example.
I would like to definie a constant vector for my class : UnityX :

```
template <typename T>
class Vector2 {

public:
    ...
    static Vector2 UnityX();
    ...

    T x,y;
};
```

And I don't know how implement it because if I do :

```
template <typename T>
Vector2<T> Vector2<T>::UnityX()
{
    return Vector2(1, 0);
}
```

I will have some warnings during compilation cause of implicit type convertion. warning C4244 from VS2013 : 'conversion' conversion from 'type1' to 'type2', possible loss of data.

To solve this I try :

```
template <typename T>
Vector2<T> Vector2<T>::UnityX()
{
    return Vector2(static_cast<T>(1.0), static_cast<T>(0.0));
}
```

With this solution, I have no more warning during compilation, but do the static_cast will not slow down performance ? Is it the best solution ?

Comment: don't worry about performance problem unless you can prove it exist. and `static_cast` is the best way to go.

Comment: what does the Vector2 constructor look like?

Comment: What is the exact warning and the code of the constructor and the type of T you are using?

Comment: I use it with int, float and double. My constructor is like this : 
'template <typename T>Vector2<T>::Vector2(T value) :
x(value),
y(value){}'

Comment: If you are concerned with performance, you can get an existing vector library that should be already debugged and optimized.

Comment: The warning is warning C4244 from VS2013 : 'conversion' conversion from 'type1' to 'type2', possible loss of data. Yes, Neil I could use an existing library but I write one myself to study,practice and I want learn best usages, for example the correct solution here.

Comment: Personally I'm not sure the use of a unity function, when they can just create a `Vector2<T>(1, 0)` vs `Vector2<T>::UnityX()`. Personally I would use static cast of `1` and `0` (not the floating points) in your code. This is just my hunch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have constant vector types you could make them static members of the class:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector2
{
public:
    Vector2(const T& x, const T& y) : x(x), y(y) {}

protected:
    T x, y;

public:
    static const Vector2<T> UnitX;
};

template <typename T>
Vector2<T> Vector2<T>::UnitX = Vector2<T>(1, 0);
```

Now using this is easy, and requires no function calls.

```
Vector2<float> unitX = Vector2<float>::UnitX;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question. He is getting a warning and wants to know how to fix it.

Comment: He's also asking **"I would like to definie a constant vector for my class"** and I'm giving advice on how it should be done.